# Mono ASP.NET GridView.Rows behavior is different from .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, mono

In my paginated GridView (contained in an UpdatePanel) bound to ObjectDataSource, I have an OnDataBound event,

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        // row isn't starting from the first row of current page in mono!
    }
}
```

When running in .NET, I `GridView.Rows` always give me the ones in the current page (i.e. GridViewRow.DataItemIndex will not be `0` but its correct index into its data source). But on Mono 2.10.8, this gives me `0` regardless of which page I'm viewing!

However, GridView.Rows[0].DataItem returns the same item as .NET. It would appear that there's a bug in DataItemIndex.

Is there a way to workaround it and achieve the same behavior as .NET on Mono and still maintain compatibility with .NET?

Comment: By that logic, .NET questions should be asked in MSDN forums. StackOverflow would be completely useless!

Comment: Well you will have a better target audience there. Use it, dont use it. Up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to achieve this.

```
public static int GetDataItemIndex(this GridViewRow row)
{
    var gridView = (GridView)row.NamingContainer;
    return row.RowIndex + (gridView.PageIndex * gridView.PageSize);
}
```

This works in both Mono and .NET.